# getting error var channel = require('cordova/channel'); in cordova.js

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am always getting this error message from cordova.js:
line 29: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

```
var channel = require('cordova/channel');
var platform = require('cordova/platform');
```

Can someone help me with this case?
Thx in advance

Comment: what was the answer?